# What is the "Helpful Flags" page about?

Tags: support

I noticed a new item on my profile page - Helpful Flags.  This links through to a page listing some statistics related to where I have been helpful (or perhaps not).  But I'm not quite sure what I am looking at.  Can anyone explain?

Comment: I don't see this page.  Can you provide a link or a screen shot?

Comment: Do you by any chance mean "helpful *flags*"?

Answer (score 3):

Helpful **flags**.  It's a summary/history of all the moderator flags you've raised, and which have been deemed helpful.

Once you have any helpful flags, and click the link, you'll get a page that looks something like the one below, but probably somewhat less awesome and impressive than mine. :)

[image: Flagged posts page]

If you explore around your page, you'll probably notice a few things.

- Only flagged *posts* are listed.  Not love for the comments, as is the SE way.
- The posts you flagged are listed and hyper-linked.
- Whatever text or reason you put into your flag is put below the post hyperlink and highlighted in yellow.
- The status of the flag, as assigned by the moderator reviewing it, is next to your text and the time of the flag.

  - Usually, but not always, "helpful" means the moderator acted on it, and "declined" means they didn't.
  - Declined flags will usually have an explanation of why they were declined by the mod declining them.

Comment: Yes - that is the page that I mean.  I had kind of gathered what you said already.  It isn't very clear as an interface.  For example, it lists a bunch of questions and then under it is some text - where did that text come from?  What does "helpful" mean, and how did it end up deemed as such?  What do the stats on the right hand side mean.  Was I helpful, or did I mark things as helpful?  What does declined mean?  This looks interesting, but it isn't intuitive to me.  Someone clearly spent some time building it - could they follow up with some more info?

Comment: @dunxd  If you have more questions, fell free to post them in the comments to this answer, and I'll edit the answers into my answer, provided I know the answer.

Comment: helpful = a mod marks it so and it means its valid. Declined means a mod didn't think it was a valid flag. enough valid flags = deputy and marshall badges.